# Inverse of SDL_GetKeyName

Tags: c, sdl

Is there a function to return a keysym from a string representation of the key?

for example, `SDL_GetKeySym("d") == SDLK_d`

I need this to read a keysym from a config file, and of course I'm using `SDL_GetKeyName` to get a string representation of the key and then saving it to the config file.

Comment: SDL-2 has `SDL_GetKeyFromName`, but it's not in SDL-1.2.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen the version doesn't matter for me, can you write an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SDL2 adds the [`SDL_GetKeyFromName`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyFromName) function, which does the inverse of `SDL_GetKeyName`.